# Marginal contribution of a text document

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-selection

I'm trying to build a Shapley value (marginal contribution) of a text document in terms of information content, given that there are several documents on a given topic.

For example, we have 3 reports describing the ocean:

A: {The ocean is blue.}

B: {The ocean is blue **and salty**.}

C: {The ocean is salty and **a home for fish**}

If I'm correct, a first step in the algorithm is identifying a set of features (individual pieces of information): {*blue, salty, a home for fish*}

Moreover, say each feature has an equal weight.

Then I can compute Shapley values of 1/6 for A, 1/3 for B, 1/2 for C.

I wonder if there are well-established algorithms / papers that deal with this problem. I'm coming from economics myself (I'm familiar with Shapley values abstractly), so apologies if the question is too trivial.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From an NLP perspective, the main issue is to identify and extract the terms/relations of interest from the text.

It may be easy if the sentences always appear like these simple examples: one can use pattern matching `"the <entity> is <property1> [and <property2>]"` (no need for ML).

However with general text it's a quite complex problem which would probably require training an ad-hoc model from annotated data. This would generally involve the tasks of [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) and [Relation Extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_extraction).